# Adding a link to a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm new to PHP & MySQL and I am trying to write a journal page for an assignment, but I am not sure how to link a query to another page that shows the full query that has been clicked. Basically so the user can access their previous journal entries. below is the code I have written so far:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['uname'];
}
require_once 'PHP/Constants.php';
$conn = new MySQLi(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die ('There was a problem connecting to the database');
$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
$query="SELECT Username, Date_Created, Title FROM journal";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Journal</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<h1>My Journal</h1>
</p>
    <?php
        echo "<table width='400' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
            <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            </tr>";
            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                if($rows['Username']=$uname) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $rows['Date_Created'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $rows['Title'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>"; 
                } else echo "No Journal Entries Found";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </table>    
<form method="post" action="new_entry.php">
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="new_entry" value="New Entry" name="new_entry" />
    </p>
</form>
<form method="post" action="choices.php">
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="back" value="Back" name="back" />
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any help - Nick

Comment: "I am not sure how to link a query to another page that shows the full query that has been clicked" -- Can you please expand on that? I'm not really sure I understand that part...

Comment: Sidenote: You're doing an assignment instead of a comparison using `if($rows['Username']=$uname)`

Comment: @FastTrack It is so the user can see other parts of the row of the database that aren't on show on this page, what their journal entry is not just the title and date

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was hoping that it would just show entries from that particular user

Comment: You need to use `==` instead of only `=` as in `if($rows['Username']==$uname)`

Comment: @NIck_Fallows your line: `$rows['Username']=$uname` should read: `$rows['Username'] == $uname`

Comment: You're welcome. So, problem solved or do you need further help?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I still need help on how to link to another page so it shows the whole journal entry so the user can see what they previously said a bit like an online diary

Comment: That will depend on how your DB is setup. Do you already have a link/URL in the said column, or do you just want to do a generic href?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just want to do a generic href but, if it is possible, open up the query that is clicked not all of them, so when they click on the title it opens that whole database entry

Comment: To do a generic link, you could do something to the effect of `echo "<td><a href='page.php'>" . $rows['Date_Created'] . " Link text</a></td>";` is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @Fred-ii- how would I then reference it in the next page?? sorry to be a pain

Comment: I need you to add some form of an example in your question, because I'm having a bit of trouble following exactly what it is you want to achieve, in regards to query (if someone clicks this link, show this) etc. - If you want a link to be accessible anywhere, you could assign it to another session variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- when the user clicks the title, for example, first, it then opens a new page that shows the title, first, and then what they have written into the diary under that title such as, This is my first entry into my journal.  This is all stored in the same table in my database, which the user has inputted into on a different page.  I could set up a page where it shows every entry however I just thought it would look better if it could just be the entry that was clicked if it possible at all

Comment: Let me think about that for a bit and I'll get back to you, whether I have a solution or not. In the meantime, see if the answer below that has been given, will do the trick.

Comment: Seems like they've closed the question, which I don't know why. Everybody needs a helping hand every once in a while. Besides that, I couldn't come up with anything to help you out with, sorry about that. Like I said I was going to let you know either way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for your help the answer below worked once I did it right lol

Comment: You're very much welcome Nick. Am glad you found a solution, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to have an ID or an unique column in your table, in this case let's say that UserName is unique. So you print your link to another php file and send that parameter by GET:

```
while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if($rows['Username']==$uname) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['Date_Created'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['Title'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='info.php?username=".$rows['Username']."'>Link</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } else 
         echo "No Journal Entries Found";
    }
}
```

Now in info.php, you recive the value and query the database using the given username:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
// Escape value to prevent SQL injection
...
$query="SELECT * FROM journal WHERE UserName = '".$username."'";
// And then display the info as you want
...
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you I have put this in however it doesn't seem to display any of the data

Comment: Thank you to everyone, I have managed to get it sorted now thanks to all your help